# Flask templates: How to call a block on a given variable?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Flask templates: How to call a block on a given variable?

I have a variable `i` that we get from the outside

How to call the `block` corresponding to the contents of this variable?

```
<p class="card-text">{% block {{ i }} %}{% endblock %}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% block blockname %} 
    {{ i }} 
{% endblock %}
```

Each block is given a unique name in the base jinja template. To include a block, it's name has to be used as per above mentioned format.